# Waiting for an event to happen?

Tags: c#, events

here is my situation:

I have class 1 that calls a method from class 2.

Class 2 does the method, and then listens for an event to happen. In this case, it waits for a the browser control to load.

How can I make class 1 wait for the event to happen in class 2?

Comment: I am programming in c#, sorry

Comment: If this is WebBrowser control we are talking about, you are probably waiting for DocumentCompleted event. Subscribe to DocumentCompleted from class1 before you set Url. You will have to split your processing to part that initializes the control and a part that does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register an idle handler in class 2's method that invokes class 1 once the control has loaded.

Comment: But how can I make class 1 wait for the response from class 2? I want it to receive the response before continuing on other instructions.

Comment: Have never used that before, will have to do some research.